# How to find the shortest distance from a point to a cycle in a directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have the following task:
Given a directed graph on  vertices, the outdegree of each vertex is equal to 1. It is necessary to find for each vertex what is the shortest distance from it to any vertex lying on the cycle in ().

I think it is necessary to use the dfs algorithm. If we have come to a point where we have already been, then all previous points (including the current one) must be marked as a cycle. Through dfs we build a dfs-tree and through it we look for the distance from the given point to the first marked point that is included in the cycle.

Are my assumptions correct? How can I prove that the asymptotic is exactly ()?

Comment: $\mathcal O(n)$ is not an "exact" thing. $\mathcal O(n) = \mathcal O(2n)$, for instance.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I understand . It is important here that this is not $O(n^2)$, etc.